# Angular unit testing with karma: Session Storage "cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service that stores basic user "config" info in session storage when the user logs in. I then call the service throughout the application to return the config when needed.

```
export class ClientConfigService {
  response: LoginConfig = initialClientConfig;
  private configResponse = new BehaviorSubject(this.response);
  configData = this.configResponse.asObservable();

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  setSessionStorage(data: LoginConfig) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('client', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.configResponse.next(data);
  }

  getClientConfig(clientId: string) {
    const clientSetup =  { startUrl: `${environment.apiUrl}/${clientId}` };

    return this.apiService.post(`yd-core/npb/start`, clientSetup).subscribe((data: LoginConfig) => {
      this.configResponse.next(data);
    });
  }

  getPageData() {
    const sessionConfig: LoginConfig = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('config'));

    return sessionConfig.client.config;
  }

  getClientId() {
    const sessionConfig: LoginConfig = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('config'));

    return sessionConfig.client.clientId;
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    const sessionConfig: LoginConfig = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('config'));

    return sessionConfig.user;
  }
}
```

When I run ng test I get many instances of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of null`

I know I need to mock session storage.. which I'm attempting here with no effect

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ClientConfigService } from './client-config.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { initialClientConfig } from '../models/user';

describe('ClientConfigService', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('client', JSON.stringify({client : {} })); 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
      ],
      providers: [
        ApiService
      ]
    })
  .compileComponents();
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: ClientConfigService = TestBed.get(ClientConfigService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: initialClientConfig is a placeHolder/default config if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably missing something, but it stands out to me that the only time you're setting `sessionStorage` is with the 'client' key, and yet every time you pull from `sessionStorage`, you're using the 'config' key. Could it be as simple as you have the keys wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I was simple naming the key wrong. I was doing

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('client', JSON.stringify({client : {} }));
```

instead of

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('config', JSON.stringify(initialClientConfig))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a dependency injection issue.  You're expecting this line to work:

```
  const service: ClientConfigService = TestBed.get(ClientConfigService);
```

When ClientConfigService is not part of your test module.  Also, Because your ClientConfigService has a dependency on ApiService; you have to be sure that you've met the dependency requirements of the ApiService service.

Ideally, in unit tests, you should only be testing one thing at a time.  I suggest that you mock out your ApiService in this test by changing this:

```
providers: [
        ApiService
      ]
```

to this:

```
providers: [
        {provide: ApiService, useValue: {"...mock properties here"}}
      ]
```

I hope this helps,
Isaac